# Jar files needed

Tags: jar

Where do I get the following jar files?

- bc.jar,
- itext-signed.jar,
- bc-signed.jar,
- toolbox.jar,
- bcmail-jdk14-137.jar,
- bcprov-jdk14-137.jar,

Precise links would be highly appreciated.

Note:
Google didn't help much.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you requested precise links, here are some:

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/itext/itext/1.1.4/itext-1.1.4.jar

http://polydistortion.net/bc/download/bcmail-jdk14-137.jar

http://polydistortion.net/bc/download/bcprov-jdk14-137.jar

jarFinder is your friend: http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars

But beware:

There are many different JAR files around the Web with the same filename.

Many different projects produce their own tool "toolbox.jar", for instance.

And then you have a different JAR for each release of each project.

Cheers,
Nicolas Raoul

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.bouncycastle.org/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/